# SQL query for percentage change compared to previous date

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table within access containing the performance of departments on different reference dates. All data is within one table "tblmain". The table contains the following fields:

- reference date (called "ref_date", formatted dd.mm.yyyy)
- department identifier (called "dep_id")
- performance value (called "val")

Every reference date consists of round about 100 departments and every week I import a new reference date.

My goal now is to build a query which calculates the percentage change from on reference date compared to the previous reference date. Furthermore, it should only show the departments with a change bigger than 5%.

I am currently stuck. I have created a query that gives me the val from the previous reference date but only for one specific department. And I do not know how to continue. This query looks as follows:

```
SELECT TOP 1 tblmain.val
FROM (SELECT TOP 2 tblmain.val, tblmain.ref_date FROM tblmain WHERE dep_id=1 ORDER BY tblmain.ref_date DESC) 
ORDER BY tblmain.ref_date;
```

I would appreciate any feedback. After finishing this query, I plan to use this query in a form where I can choose an reference date and threshold.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Based on the syntax of the query and your original tags, I assume you intend MS Access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Query to pull prior val for each record:

```
SELECT tblMain.ID, tblMain.ref_date, tblMain.dep_id, tblMain.val, 
    (SELECT TOP 1 val FROM tblMain AS Dupe 
     WHERE Dupe.dep_id=tblMain.dep_id AND Dupe.ref_Date < tblMain.ref_date 
     ORDER BY dupe.ref_date) AS PriorVal
FROM tblMain;
```

Now use that query to calculate percentage:

```
SELECT Query1.*, Abs(([PriorVal]-[val])/[PriorVal]*100) AS P
FROM Query1
WHERE (((Abs(([PriorVal]-[val])/[PriorVal]*100))>5));
```

Comment: Dear June,
many thanks for your answer!! It was perfect to find the best solution for my problem. 
There was just missing a DESC after the "ORDER BY dupe.ref_date". The result is a table adding a column with all previous values. 
For my report to just see the last result, I have added a TOP 1 at the beginning and an "ORDER BY tblMain.ref_date DESC" at the end.